# Efficient algorithm for determining values not as frequent in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, frequency

I am building a quiz application which pulls questions randomly from a pool of questions.  However, there is a requirement that the pool of questions be limited to questions that the user has not already seen.  If, however, the user has seen all the questions, then the algorithm should "reset" and only show questions the user has seen once.  That is, always show the user questions that they have never seen or, if they have seen all of them, always show them questions they have seen less frequently before showing questions they have seen more frequently.

The list (L) is created in a such a way that the following is true: any value in the list (I), may exist once or be repeated in the list multiple times.  Let's define another value in the list, J, such that it's not the same value as I.  Then `0 <= abs(frequency(I) - frequency(J)) <= 1` will always be true.

To put it another way: if a value is repeated in the list 5 times, and 5 times is the maximum number of times any value has been repeated in the list, then all values in the list will be repeated either 4 or 5 times.  The algorithm should return all values in the list with `frequency == 4` before it returns any with `frequency == 5`.

Sorry this is so verbose, I'm struggling to define this problem succinctly.  Please feel free to leave comments with questions and I will further qualify if needed.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

**Clarification**

Thank you for the proposed answers so far.  I don't think any of them are there yet.  Let me further explain.

I'm not interacting with the user and asking them questions.  I'm assigning the question ids to an exam record so that when the user begins an exam, the list of questions they have access to is determined.  Therefore, I have two data structures to work with:

- List of possible question ids that the user has access to
- List of all question ids this user has ever been assigned previously.  This is the list L described above.

So, unless I am mistaken, the algorithm/solution to this problem will need to involve list &/or set based operations using the two lists described above.

The result will be a list of question ids I can associate with the exam record and then insert into the database.

Comment: I think the problem is much simpler than you have put it. I have your solution below that does not use multiple lists or pivots, and is much easier to code. Let me know if there's something that's insufficient. Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @AaronHall please see the clarification in my question.  Also, I am using Python 2.

Comment: Requirements creep; not even coders can resist.  I believe my edited answer saves you a step and gets to the same info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
from collections import Counter
import random

# the number of question ids I need returned to
# assign to the exam
needed = 3

# the "pool" of possible question ids the user has access to
possible = [1,2,3,4,5]

# examples of lists of question ids I might see that represent
# questions a user has already answered
answered1 = []
answered2 = [1,3]
answered3 = [5,4,3,2]
answered4 = [5,4,3,2,1,1,2]
answered5 = [5,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,1]
answered6 = [5,4,3,2,1]

def getdiff(answered):
    diff = set(possible) - set(answered)
    still_needed = needed - len(diff)
    if still_needed > 0:
        not_already_selected = list(set(possible) - diff)
        random.shuffle(not_already_selected)
        diff = list(diff) + not_already_selected[0:still_needed]
        random.shuffle(diff)
        return diff
    diff = list(diff)
    random.shuffle(diff)
    if still_needed == 0:
        return diff
    return diff[0:needed]

def workit(answered):
    """ based on frequency, reduce the list down to only
        those questions we want to consider "answered"
    """
    have_count = 0
    if len(possible) > len(answered):
        return getdiff(answered)
    counted = Counter(answered)
    max_count = max(counted.values())
    # the key here is to think of "answered" questions as
    # only those that have been seen with max frequency
    new_answered = []
    for value, count in counted.iteritems():
        if count == max_count:
            new_answered.append(value)
    return getdiff(new_answered)

print 1, workit(answered1)
print 2, workit(answered2)
print 3, workit(answered3)
print 4, workit(answered4)
print 5, workit(answered5)
print 6, workit(answered6)

"""
>>> 
1 [2, 4, 3]
2 [2, 5, 4]
3 [5, 2, 1]
4 [5, 3, 4]
5 [2, 4, 3]
6 [2, 3, 5]
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
1 [3, 1, 4]
2 [5, 2, 4]
3 [2, 4, 1]
4 [5, 4, 3]
5 [4, 5, 3]
6 [1, 5, 3]
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
1 [1, 2, 3]
2 [4, 2, 5]
3 [4, 1, 5]
4 [5, 4, 3]
5 [2, 5, 4]
6 [2, 1, 4]
"""
```

Answer (score 7):

Rewritten with the database stuff in fill-in pseudocode.

If I understand the problem correctly, I'd treat the questions (or their IDs as proxies) like a physical deck of cards: for each user, shuffle the deck and deal them a question at a time; if they want more than `len(deck)` questions, just start over: shuffle the deck into a new order and do it again. When a question is seen for the `n`th time, all other questions will have been seen `n` or `n-1` times.

To keep track of what questions the user has had available, we put the *unused* question IDs back in the database and increment the "how many times through" counter whenever we need a new deal.

Something like:

```
from random import shuffle

def deal():
    question_IDs = get_all_questions(dbconn) # all questions
    shuffle(question_IDs)
    increment_deal_count(dbconn, userID) # how often this student has gotten questions
    return question_IDs


count_deals = get_stored_deals(dbconn, userID) # specific to this user
if count_deals: 
    question_IDs = get_stored_questions(dbconn, userID) # questions stored for this user 
else: # If 0 or missing, this is the first time for this student
    question_IDs = deal()


while need_another_question(): #based on exam requirements
    try:
        id = question_IDs.pop()
    except IndexError:
        question_IDs = deal()
        id = question_IDs.pop() # Trouble if db is ever empty. 

    use_question(id) # query db with the ID, then put question in print, CMS, whatever

# When we leave that while loop, we have used at least some of the questions
# question_IDs lists the *unused* ones for this deal
# and we know how many times we've dealt.

store_in_db(dbconn, userinfo, question_IDs)
# If you want to know how many times a question has been available, it's
# count_deals - (ID in question_IDs)
# because True evaluates to 1 if you try to subtract it from an integer.
```

Comment: You need to shuffle only the part of the questions list that hasn't been chosen, otherwise this wouldn't satisfy the condition that most frequently picked question are only picked once more than the least frequently picked question. Also, shuffling the entire unpicked questions list just to pick one random quesion is overkill and unnecessary.

Comment: This only shuffles the questions list while the whole questions list hasn't been chosen (or when starting over), so I don't believe the first sentence is a problem. 

I agree that if the question list is large, shuffling everything is inefficient. But if it isn't large, this approach is simpler than  the pivot. (Editing to add, simpler for the coder.)

Comment: Ah, you're correct; I must have had some reading difficulties today.

Comment: It's more pythonic to iterate over a list by element, not by index.

Comment: I agree with @AaronHall, n.b.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.  I have clarified in my question that I am not interacting with the user.  The end result of my algorithm needs to be a set of ids I can insert into a db.

Comment: It doesn't really matter that you're *getting* them from a db, it does matter that you need to store them there. Rewritten in pseudocode handling question IDs.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't want to store any other info in the db other than the questions I have available and the questions the user has already answered.  The question I asked was particular to the database structure I had available.  Your answer may work, but not for my use case.

Answer (score 5):

Why not have *two* lists, one for questions not yet picked and one for questions that have been picked. Initially, the not-yet-picked list will be full, and you will pick elements from it which will be removed and added to the picked list. Once the not-yet-picked list is empty, repeat the same process as above, this time using the full picked list as the not-yet-picked list and vice versa.

Comment: And shuffle the full list each time, to satisfy the randomness request? Nice. (*Duh*, pick randomly. Nevermind.)

Comment: A separate list is far less efficient than simply going through the shuffled list once.

Comment: @cphlewis Yes, exactly. :)

Comment: @AaronHall I wouldn't expect there to be a performance concern here. From what I gather based on the OP's question, it makes sense logically to think of "picked" and "not yet picked" as two different collections of elements, which is why I favored this approach.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.  Because I am getting my two lists by querying a db, I can't do as you suggest.  Please see my updated question for the nature of the two lists that I am starting with.

Comment: @Randy your comments make no sense. Your inability to apply the suggested approaches to a particular scenario do not make them invalid. Instead of reiterating your question you should ask a new question altogether

Answer (score 3):

To implement your algorithm, you only need to shuffle the list and pass through it, and when done, repeat.

No need to copy the list or juggle items between two lists, just use the following control flow, for example:

```
import random

def ask_questions(list_of_questions):
    while True:
        random.shuffle(list_of_questions)
        for question in list_of_questions:
            print(question)
            # Python 3 use input not raw_input
            cont = raw_input('Another question?') 
            if not cont:
                break
        if not cont:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's define a "pivot" that separates a list into two sections. The pivot partitions the array such that all numbers before the pivot has been picked one more than the numbers after the pivot (or more generally, all numbers before pivot are ineligible for picking, while all numbers after the pivot are eligible for picking).

You simply need to pick a random item from the list of numbers after the pivot, swap it with the number on the pivot, and then increment the pivot. When the pivot reaches the end of the list, you can reset it back to the start.

Alternatively, you can also use two lists, which is much easier to implement, but is *slightly* less efficient as it needs to expand/shrink the list. Most of the time, the ease of implementation would trump the inefficiency so the two-list would usually be my first choice.

Comment: I think what you propose has merit.  The issue is, how do I determine where my pivot is?  See my updated question for clarification on the nature of the two lists I have to work with.